# GraphQL Parse error on \"-\" (error) at [2, 33]

Tags: graphql, github-api

I am trying to return the query from function to another but when executing this function it throws an error

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on \"-\" (error) at [2, 61]","locations":[{"line":2,"column":61}]}]},..}
```

What I am doing wrong?How should I pass the query?

```
export function queryDependencyGraph(owner: string, repository: string) {
    return `query ($owner: String!, $repository: String!) {
        repository(owner: ${owner}, name: ${repository}) {
          url
          name
          dependencyGraphManifests(withDependencies: true) {
            nodes{
              dependencies {
                nodes{
                  packageManager
                  packageName
                  requirements
                }
              }
            }
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
              endCursor
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
  const query = queryDependencyGraph("abcd-defg", repoName)
  const headers : Record<string, string> = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.hawkgirl-preview+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
  const variables : Record<string, string> = {
    owner: 'abcd-defg', 
    repository: 'xxx'}

  const headers : Record<string, string> = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.hawkgirl-preview+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
const response = await graphqlRequest("https://api.github.com/graphql", { query: query, headers : headers });
```

Comment: It looks like the code for `query` running at https://api.github.com/graphql doesn't like an `owner` that has a hyphen in it: `'abcd-defg'` even though it's a `string`.

Comment: @MichelFloyd how should it looks like. I tried ```repository(owner: "${owner}")``` but did not help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing string literal syntax into GraphQL.

Where you have:

```
repository(owner: ${owner}, name: ${repository}) {
```

Use:

```
repository(owner: $owner, name: $repository) {
```

`variables` are defined in an object where the keys are the variable names you have in the query.

Another thing missing is that you are not passing the `variables` variable into `graphqlRequest` - I'm not sure which graphql client you're using here but look at the docs for `graphqlRequest` and see where `variables` go. I would suspect something like:

```
const response = await graphqlRequest(
  "https://api.github.com/graphql",
  { query, variables, headers }
);
```

Comment: But then how should i PASS these parameters to this function. When I tried like above, it also did not work, cause could not able to pass the argument.

```export function queryDependencyGraph(owner: string, repository: string)```